# How to remove MBR and replace GRUB?

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, mbr

About 2 weeks ago on Friday, so exactly 2 weeks ago, I accidentally screwed up GRUB on Ubuntu 13.04(64-bit). I don't remember how, but I did. I tried fixing it on my own. Tried several boot repair disks, and couldn't figure it out. Then one day, I decided to try to install MBR on one of my repair disks. Sadly, that kept me from even reaching the boot screen. Now I can't remove that. The only way I can boot Linux Mint and Ubuntu now is through Super GRUB Repair or something. It's in the Rescatux thing..... Anyway, there is an option that allows you to look for Operating Systems on the computer. It finds both Ubuntu and Linux, but only Linux is bootable because grub is fine. But Ubuntu, grub is messed up and its the primary operating system. I had booting from a disk every time and I'd like to get it fixed. I have to go out of state Sunday, but I only have internet until Saturday.

I'd also like to add that I'm willing to risk losing data if I must reinstall Ubuntu. I noticed in the installer that I can reinstall, but it insists that I backup before doing so, but I can't even access /home/User/ so.. I mean, I can look into User, but I can't actually see Desktop, Downloads, Documents, etc. I can only see Access-your-private-data.Desktop and README.txt.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair I had to use it on numerous occasions - it never let me down!